# Extract Links Data and reformat them into a table

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to know if it is possible to extract a href data from a website page and input it into a table using jQuery. My clients usually want me to take a bunch links from their old sites and bring them into my CMS. If there is a way to put these links into a spreadsheet, then I can easily import them into my CMS system.

Here is an example of a link directory:

```
   <div class="group">
    <h1>Header 1</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://link.com">Link Name A</a>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
<div class="group">
    <h1>Header 2</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://link.com">Link Name A</a>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

The script would take the header, the link name, and the url and reformat it like the following:

```
<table>
    <thead>

        <td>Link Name</td>
        <td>Url</td>
        <td>Category</td>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Link Name A</td>
            <td>http://link.com</td>
            <td>Header 1</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Link Name A</td>
            <td>http://link.com</td>
            <td>Header2</td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are other ways, but this will do what you ask based on the structure you provided. If the HTML structure is different, you will need to adjust:

```
 $(".group h1").each(function(){
    //loop though each h1
    //get h1
    var head = $(this).html()

    //get the li element
    var linkEl = $(this).next('ul').find('li')

    //get link text
    var linkTxt = linkEl.find('a').text()

    //get link url
    var linkURL = linkEl.find('a').attr('href')

    //add them to the table
    $("tbody").append("<tr><td>"+linkTxt+"</td><td>"+linkURL+"</td><td>"+head+"</td></tr>")
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x040mx73/1/